# Log-likelihood function for CoxTimeVaryingFitter

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard, weibull-distribution, proportional-hazards

The **mathematical formulation** of partial log-likelihood function (https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/cox-proportional-hazard-regression.html) is defined as:

[image]

The above formulation does not take into account the 'id' information.

And in the documentation of CoxTimeVaryingFitter (https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Time%20varying%20survival%20regression.html) an 'id' column is used as such:

[image]

By executing 'ctv' in Python, we get the values of the regression coefficient beta.

And beta values are obtained by maximizing the partial log-likelihood function

Thus, how is the 'id' column used to define the **mathematical formulation** of the log-likelihood function?

Can somebody please help me out with understanding this concept?